# How to add suggestions from a list of words in a bootstrap search box

Tags: html

I have used a search box in my code.

```
 <form action="/search" method="post" role="form">
 <div id="custom-search-input" style="height:41px">
 <div class="input-group col-md-12" style="height:10px">
 <input id="search" name="search" type="text" class="form-control input-lg"  
                 placeholder="Search"  style="font-size:14px;height:30px"/>
 <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="submit">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="text-decoration:none"></i>
        </button>
         </span>
         </div>
  <div><label id="noresult"><i>No results found</i></label>
  </div>
   </div>
   </form>
```

Now i want to add auto suggestions to this search box like if you write "a" it starts showing everything starting with "a" just like google.Those suggestions can be loaded from a list which contains every possible result that can be searched.

Please help me about how to add this feature.

Comment: use jquery autocomplete - https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only by `HTML` you can't do this.

You have to use `javascript`.

Here is a solution using `jquery`.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="selector">
```

**JS**

```
var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Cycle",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"];
$("#selector").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
});

$('#selector').change(function () {
    alert($('#selector').val());
});
```

Before using this you have to add `jquery` and `jquery-ui`.

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/ekhT4/1/)**

Comment: I used it...It is working well.. But the problem is that it shifts the consecutive divs down when suggestions open. So is there a way to suggestion box over the consecutive divs so they don't get shifted and also search suggestions are visible. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: can you reproduce it fiddle I will check it.